# Getting form to post to php file that sends email, then redirects to correct paypal option purchase page

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I have a form that collects users information to register for a golf tournament. Currently, after the form is completed, it posts to php file that sends me an email with the form contents, then redirects the user to a second page, where they select the registration package they wish to purchase and are redirected to a paypal page to complete the purchase.

What I'd like to do is combine both forms, so that the user fills in his information, selects his registration package, hits the submit button, the php file sends me the email, then redirects to the correct paypal payment page for which option they selected.

If possible, I'd like to do this without javascript, but am not sure how to pull the correct api calls from the form into the php file and then redirect to the correct paypal payment page, depending on the option selected.

Current form:

```
<form name="golfsignup" method="Post" action="golfformsignup.php" onsubmit="return validate();">
                <table>
                <tbody><tr><td>Sponsor Name</td><td><input type="edit" name="Sponsor_Name__1" value="" size="20"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Street Address</td><td><input type="edit" name="Street_Address__2" value="" size="30"></td></tr>
                <tr class="city partial"><td>City</td><td><input type="edit" name="City__3" value="" size="30"></td></tr>
                <tr class="state partial"><td>State</td><td><input type="edit" name="State__4" value="" size="30"></td></tr>
                <tr class="zip partial"><td>Zip Code (xxxxx)</td><td><input type="edit" name="Zip_Code_xxxxx__5" value="" size="5"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Phone Number (No Spaces or Dashes)</td><td><input type="edit" name="Phone_Number_No_Spaces_or_Dashes__6" value="" size="13"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Team Name</td><td><input type="edit" name="Team_Name__7" value="" size="30"></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" valign="top">Team Player Names<br><textarea name="Team_Player_Names__8" cols="30" size="4"></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Name on Credit Card</td><td><input type="edit" name="Name_on_Credit_Card__9" value="" size="50"></td></tr>
                <table>
                    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Golf Tournament">Please proceed to PayPal to complete transaction.</td></tr><tr><td><select id="selectValue" name="os0">
                        <option value="Team">Team $900.00 USD</option>
                        <option value="Individual">Individual $225.00 USD</option>
                    </select> </td></tr>
                </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd__10" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id__11" value="5820LFRI32195">
                <tr><td colspan="2">
                    <span id="bull"></span> <!-- target for nav with js disabled -->
                    <input id="golfButton" title="Register via PayPal" class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register Team">
                    </td></tr></tbody></table>

            </form>
```

PHP script

```
<?php session_start();

$youremail = 'jdhancock@gmail.com';
$fromsubject = 'Golf Signup';
$fname = $_POST['Sponsor_Name__1'];
$phone = $_POST['Phone_Number_No_Spaces_or_Dashes__6'];
$subject = $_POST['Team_Name__7'];
$message = $_POST['Team_Player_Names__8'];
$to = $youremail;
$mailsubject = 'Message received from'.$fromsubject.' Golf Registration Page';
$body = $fromsubject.';
The person that contacted you is '.$fname.'
Phone Number: '.$phone.'
Subject: '.$subject.'
Team Member Names:
'.$message.'
|---------END MESSAGE----------|';


mail($to, $subject, $body);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. You might add the following code after your mail() function.
When the button is pressed, your mail is send, the payment query string is build from the form data, the method header() redirect the user directly to the paypal site.

It contains some unset vars: so please replace vars like $first_name with your incomming $_POST data. It does not work out of the box - it's just a pointer in the right direction.

Important is to change the price and item name based on the dropdown, see the if-condition.

```
// build a new PayPal GET query string
$query = array();
$query['notify_url'] = 'http://yourPaymentNotifyPage.com/';
$query['cmd'] = '_cart';
$query['upload'] = '1';
$query['business'] = 'your@business.com';
$query['address_override'] = '1';
$query['first_name'] = $first_name; 
$query['last_name'] = $last_name;
$query['email'] = $email;
$query['address1'] = $ship_to_address;
$query['city'] = $ship_to_city;
$query['state'] = $ship_to_state;
$query['zip'] = $ship_to_zip;

// now: use the value from your dropdown (select os0)
// to set different price and name for this payment
if($_POST['os0'] === 'Team') {
   $query['item_name_1'] = 'Team Golf';
   $query['quantity_1'] = 1;
   $query['amount_1'] = '900';
}
if($_POST['os0'] === 'Individual') {
   $query['item_name_1'] = 'Individual Golf';
   $query['quantity_1'] = 1;
   $query['amount_1'] = '225';
}

// Prepare query string
$query_string = http_build_query($query);
// redirect
header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . $query_string);
```

For testing:

- https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/ipn-test-outside
- https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (URL for header redirection)